# Error on setting app icon

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I just concluded my app, so I want to set an Icon. I downloaded a Mac App which I just drag the image wanted and it converts automatically to 2x and 3x. However, when I run the app on my iPhone the icon doesn't appear, remaining only the standard production icon. What might be happening? Can you guys give me a hand please? I'll post some pictures below.

[App Icons Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bs19.png)

[App icon on the Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0dIj.png)

[App icon on my iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIUrY.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the phone and reinstalling through Xcode?

Comment: You are not helping yourself.

Comment: I already did it! Unfortunately still the same @MultiColourPixel

Comment: Hello @ElTomato! What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already ran into that.

One thing I did was to uninstall the whole app from your phone / iPad, and reinstall it. Sometime Xcode doesn't get all the changes I guess.

I don't know if it helped, but that's what I did last summer (2017).

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, I already tried it many times I don’t really know what might be happening. I’m using the BETA XCode, could be that?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the project using **XCode 9.4** instead of **XCode 10 beta**. After that I just run the app on my cellphone and magically the app icon appeared!

Thank you all